# Usability of Purchase Experience

Tags: gui-design, user-behavior, user-expectation, user-centered-design

This is a product card within a carousel, showing a past purchases and aims to encourage a repurchase.

My question is, does the interaction at the bottom of the card get missed? Do you understand what to do here? (You can rate the wine and tap the bottom to see tasting notes and add your own tasting notes.)

All opinions welcome.

[image: Image of product card within a carousel]

Comment: I would rephrase your question to make this more valuable to the community. Look at the guidelines about questions. You have a common problem, but it's not just a 'UI review' question. The deeper problem is about what to prioritize, and the outcome you want for the business goals.

Answer (score 1):

#### The primary goal is to have them repurchase. Can you drop the other asks of them?

**Don't distract them from the purchase process.**

So you have 2 things you're asking of the customer here, all while you're getting them to do the main thing: hit that <kbd>BUY AGAIN</kbd> button.

The first (thumbs up, thumbs down) seems unnecessary because if they like the wine, they'd just buy it again.

The second (tasting notes) is really for your company to sell more wine by building up some kind of (recommendation engine?). Could you do that after the purchase in some way?

The main thing is to separate the purchase process from the review process. Even from just a graphic design perspective, the Tasting Notes bar is bigger than the <kbd>BUY AGAIN</kbd> button. They don't need to live together.

If you must have them together, try putting the review subordinate to any purchase call-to-action, or near the purchase history. They can follow the link to leave a review.

- You might also try to deemphasize the 'Complete' green. Since the purchase was completed, do you need to have this here? At the very least you can lessen the emphasis
- Try making the CTA button more noticeable. I know it's the brand color, but perhaps it can stand out more. Right now the 50% off and the Complete lozenge are more colorful.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @mike.

I'll definitely take these notes on; reduce the importance of the complete tag, maybe even remove. And I'll make the  cta larger than rating.
We wanted to keep the interactive components together and below the cta. But I like how small you've made it. The concern people won't see it.

Quick rational; The rating is for the customer, (we offer 900+ bottles) and a bit of gamification. It will also teach us, the business, what they like and can serve them similar wines. The tasting notes are private for the customer to add (for MVP phase).

Thanks!

Comment: Maired, you should add this as a comment on Mike's answer or edit your own question.